# Polars - date time conversion to local timezone

Tags: python-polars

I've a dataframe with unix timestamp and the converted UTC timestamp. Now I need to convert this data into local timezone, given in the zone_info column

```
┌───────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ utc_timestamp ┆ zone_info       ┆ UTC                     ┆ Chicago                       │
│ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---                     ┆ ---                           │
│ i64           ┆ str             ┆ datetime[μs, UTC]       ┆ datetime[μs, America/Chicago] │
╞═══════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════╡
│ 1641962894    ┆ America/Chicago ┆ 2022-01-12 04:48:14 UTC ┆ 2022-01-11 22:48:14 CST       │
│ 1641962904    ┆ America/Chicago ┆ 2022-01-12 04:48:24 UTC ┆ 2022-01-11 22:48:24 CST       │
│ 1641962993    ┆ America/Chicago ┆ 2022-01-12 04:49:53 UTC ┆ 2022-01-11 22:49:53 CST       │
│ 1641963730    ┆ America/Chicago ┆ 2022-01-12 05:02:10 UTC ┆ 2022-01-11 23:02:10 CST       │
│ 1641963950    ┆ America/Chicago ┆ 2022-01-12 05:05:50 UTC ┆ 2022-01-11 23:05:50 CST       │
└───────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
```

How can I use the zone_info column as an argument in this snippet.

```
pdf2 = pdf1.with_columns(pl.col("UTC").dt.convert_time_zone(time_zone="America/Chicago").alias("Chicago"))
```

I tried this

```
pdf2 = pdf1.with_columns(pl.col("UTC").dt.convert_time_zone(time_zone=pl.col("zone_info")).alias("Chicago"))
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: argument 'time_zone': 'Expr' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: You probably need to open a [feature request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/) for `.convert_time_zone()` to accept expressions.

Comment: @jqurious Given that datetime columns have to be the same timezone, I'd think the feature request wouldn't go anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
df.with_columns(
    local_time=(
        pl.coalesce(
            pl.when(pl.col('zone_info')==tz)
              .then(pl.col('UTC').dt.convert_time_zone(tz))
        for tz in df['zone_info'].unique())
        )
)
```

However, that only works if all the timezones are the same since a datetime column has to be in the same timezone. You can't mix and match. Given that, you might as well just do:

```
df.with_columns(
    local_time=pl.col('UTC').dt.convert_time_zone(df['zone_info'][0])
)
```

You could do a version of the first one if you tack on a `to_string("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")` in order to have just the string representation of a wide array of different time zones.